# Android mobile app : Not able to find object in appium or browserstack inspect mode

Tags: android, appium-android

in android app, I am not able to find the locators or objects. I am getting `android.widget.HorizontalScrollView` and inside that `android.View.ViewGroup`. Where as there are buttons, cards inside that block

I want to automate this and want click on button for which its not showing separate object

Comment: Could you confirm whether there's any webview object wrapping the elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the locator by clicking on the text element when the Appium not able to find the locator, for example:

> this.btnSkip = '//*[@text="SKIP"]';